# Create a variable to invoke a data.frame in R

Tags: r, dplyr

So I have created a program that runs a summary and anova as well as plots some graphs for me. The problem is that for each new data frame I use I need to change the variables inside the formulas. What I want to do is create a variable at the beginning of the script that I assign to the column I'm interested in and then the program does the work:

```
mydata <- Leaves.data.csv
attach(mydata)
str(mydata)

var <- Leaves

avgVaL <- group_by(mydata, Treatment, Medium, Treatment:Medium) %>% 
summarise(count=sum(!is.na(var)), mean = mean(var, na.rm = T), sd = sd(var, na.rm=T), se = sd/sqrt(count))
```

The only thing I wish to change is `Leaves`. The problem with this code is `summarise` takes `var` as 1 single variable and returns the count, mean, sd and se of the all the data points instead of each group.

Comment: See `vignette("programming")` or [here](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/dplyr/vignettes/programming.html)

Comment: Maybe because you're grouping by `Treatment:Medium`, which considers all columns (between them)? Do you really need that when you already have `group_by(mydata, Treatment, Medium)`?

Comment: @AntoniosK It is indeed not useful but I just find it handy for data visualization. As for deleting it did not work.

Comment: @A.Suliman this seems to provide the solution. I'll work on it an upload it if I get it to work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end I needed to use the `quo()` function as this function quotes my input rather than evaluation, thus (if I understand correctly) quoting would be similar to calling in other programming languages, which means you invoke directly that variable from the original data frame rather than creating a new one altogether.
At the same time you have to use `!!` behind every call inside the function of interest as this tells the function to evaluate the already quoted variable (rather than quoting again).

Much better explained: https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/dplyr/vignettes/programming.html

The code:

```
var <- quo(Root.growth)
avgVar <- group_by(mydata, Treatment, Medium) 
%>% summarise(count=sum(!is.na(!!var)), mean = mean(!!var, na.rm = T), sd = sd(!!var, na.rm=T), se = sd/sqrt(count))
```